# How can I refer to a 2-dimensional infinite range i.e. an infinite table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My spreadsheet will automatically add extra rows and columns over time. What can I replace the value `T99` with to make the range infinite in size downwards and horizontally across from the A2 cell?

```
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 8th column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 8;
  var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to sort.

  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );

}
```

I know that I can use `A2:A` for infinite columns and `A2:2` for infinite rows, but not sure how to this for a 2 dimensional range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sh.getRange(startrow,startcolumn,sh.getLastRow()-startRow+1,sh.getLastColumn()-startcolumn+1);
```

I wouldn't called it infinite...

In your code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();  
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).sort({column:8,ascending:true});
}
```

Comment: How do I actually input this into my code? I have been trying to work it out, but haven't got it.

Answer (score 0):

The term that I use instead of "infinite range" is "open-ended". By the way, `A2:A` and `A2:2` are 2 dimensional ranges, the first has one column and multiple rows, the second has one row and multiple columns.

Just replace `"A2:T99"` by `"A2:T"`. Please bear in mind that this will take all the rows. One easy way to prevent having blank rows shown on top is to delete them, specially before sorting.

Your function with the above change

```
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 8th column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */

function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 8;
  var tableRange = "A2:T"; // What to sort.

  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );

}
```

Comment: I need it to be open-ended in both rows and columns though, so T in `A2:T` needs to be a dynamic value. 

I do have some other issues, which you've touched on. If I use descending sort, then I get all the blank rows at the top of the sheet. However if I add new row using my Python API, that new row will not adopt the formulas that the rest of the spreadsheet has. The only way that I can think to solve this currently is to have my Python programme input the formulas for the new row, but this is not ideal as it adds complexity to the programme. Would you know of a way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. There is no A1 Notation for an open-end in both dimensions so you should use something else. Regarding the other issues I suggest you to post a new question including more details about the structure of your sheet (consider to post two, one for the sorting issue an another for copying the formulas when inserting rows with your Python programme)